# Displaying a Facebook Page Feed on a Wordpress Page

Tags: facebook, wordpress, rss, feed

As the title suggests, I'm trying to display a Facebook Page's feed on a specific page on my website..

Not really sure what the easiest way to do this would be, tried using LifeStream but it was giving me errors when I tried to access it's settings, so scratch that.

Any help to link me to a solution (or give me a solution!) is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin -> http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-feed-grabber/

This widget-> http://wordpress.org/plugins/fbf-facebook-page-feed-widget/

other; http://wordpress.org/plugins/jsl3-facebook-wall-feed/, http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-facebook-feed/

Answer (score 1):

The [like box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) should get you what you need, with only a bit of Javascript or an iframe needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [page badge](https://www.facebook.com/badges/page.php) and copy its code in a Text widget.